# Hide Jobs from Spring Batch Admin

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, spring-batch-admin

I would like to hide some jobs from the "Job Names Registered" list on Spring Batch Admin Job's tab.

I'm using an old version, 'spring-batch-core-2.2.6.RELEASE' and 'spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.RELEASE', and I didn't find anything helpful on the bean definition tag into the org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/spring-batch-2.2.xsd

So before doing 'dirty' things on the Controller or remove from the obj #list jobs, on the jobs.ftl, the unwanted jobs I'm asking for something I'm not still able to find.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jobs listed come from those in the `JobRegistry`.  By default, Spring Batch Admin uses an `AutomaticJobRegistrar` which loads all the jobs in the application contexts.  However, in your case, you should be able to override that bean (`jobLoader`) in your override configuration and provide your own registrar that loads only the jobs you want.  You can read more about overriding beans in Spring Batch Admin in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.xhtml

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. At the moment I'm happy overriding the `org/springframework/batch/admin/web/JobController.java`  
  
My Admin page calls the REST endpoint GET "/jobs/" where I made a couple of single changes.